# Subtracting timestamps in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Ok I have 2 columns: **last_time_used** and **prev_time_used**. I am trying to write a query that will get all the records that have a time difference of 2 hours. E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE last_time_used - prev_time_used >= 2
```

The above query gets and an error saying it expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND but got a number.

I have seen similar questions on here but none that seem to fit what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What is the data type of these two columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With timestamp arithmetics you need to use the INTERVAL data type:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE last_time_used - prev_time_used >= interval '2' hour
```

Note: code not tested.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this matrix: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#g196492

some examples:
TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP returns INTERVAL
DATE - DATE returns NUMBER (number of days)
DATE - TIMESTAMP returns INTERVAL
etc.